# how to change outliers using numpy and scipy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Im trying to remove outliers using numpy (without using pandas).
I have an array I created who looks like this:

```
[[-9.00681170e-01  1.01900435e+00 -1.34022653e+00 -1.31544430e+00]
[-1.14301691e+00 -1.31979479e-01 -1.34022653e+00 -1.31544430e+00]
[-1.38535265e+00  3.28414053e-01 -1.39706395e+00 -1.31544430e+00]
[-1.50652052e+00  9.82172869e-02 -1.28338910e+00 -1.31544430e+00]
[-1.02184904e+00  1.24920112e+00 -1.34022653e+00 -1.31544430e+00]
[-5.37177559e-01  1.93979142e+00 -1.16971425e+00 -1.05217993e+00]
[-1.50652052e+00  7.88807586e-01 -1.34022653e+00 -1.18381211e+00]
[-1.02184904e+00  7.88807586e-01 -1.28338910e+00 -1.31544430e+00]]
```

and I want to create a function that checks that array and if it finds any number that:
x>=3 it will replace it with 2.9
and if it find a number that x<=-3 it will replace it with -2.9
I have tried two different ways:
first I tried to write it like this:

```
def ignoreOutlieres(array):
for i in array:
  for x in i:
      x = float(format(x,".2f"))
      if x >= 3:
          x = 2.99
      elif x <= -3:
          x = -2.99
return array
```

but I got this type error:

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Then I tried to use numpt and z test:

```
def ignoreOutlieres(num_array):
for i in num_array:
    i = np.all(stats.zscore(i)>=3, axis = 2.9)
    return num_array
```

but I dont think I really got the idea behind it and Im not using it correctly.
Ill aprreaciate any kind of help or guidance.
The output I want to get in the end looks something like that:

```
[[-0.90068117,  1.01900435, -1.34022653, -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.14301691, -0.13197948, -1.34022653, -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.38535265,  0.32841405, -1.39706395, -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.50652052,  0.09821729, -1.2833891 , -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.02184904,  1.24920112, -1.34022653, -1.3154443 ],
                [-0.53717756,  1.93979142, -1.16971425, -1.05217993],
                [-1.50652052,  0.78880759, -1.34022653, -1.18381211],
                [-1.02184904,  0.78880759, -1.2833891 , -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.74885626, -0.36217625, -1.34022653, -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.14301691,  0.09821729, -1.2833891 , -1.44707648],
                [-0.53717756,  1.47939788, -1.2833891 , -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.26418478,  0.78880759, -1.22655167, -1.3154443 ],
                [-1.26418478, -0.13197948, -1.34022653, -1.44707648],
                [-1.87002413, -0.13197948, -1.51073881, -1.44707648],
                [-0.05250608,  2.16998818, -1.45390138, -1.3154443 ],
                [-0.17367395, 2.9       , -1.2833891 , -1.05217993],
                [-0.53717756,  1.93979142, -1.39706395, -1.05217993],
                [-0.90068117,  1.01900435, -1.34022653, -1.18381211],
                [-0.17367395,  1.70959465, -1.16971425, -1.18381211],
                [-0.90068117,  1.70959465, -1.2833891 , -1.18381211]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use loops when you work with numpy. You need `np.where`, which is the numpy's combined equivalent of `for` and `if`:

```
patched = np.where(array <= -3, -2.99, 
                   np.where(array >= 3, 2.99, array))
```

Comment: but where I define the a?
Im not suppose to define it by writing:
`for a in array:`

Comment: `array` is your array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy's indexing to change these values. `numpy_array >= 3` returns a boolean array so `numpy_array[numpy_array >= 3] = 2.99` replaces every location where `numpy_array >= 3` evaluates to `True` to `2.99`.

```
def change_outliers(numpy_array):
    numpy_array[numpy_array >= 3] = 2.99
    numpy_array[numpy_array <= -3] = -2.99
    return numpy_array
```

Comment: just to understand, if it wont find any numbers that are >= 3 , will it return false?

Comment: @ranbar Yes. If the array is `[1 1 2 2]` it returns `[False False False False]` so there will be no values that will be changed